# fetch data from secure api with axios in react native

Tags: react-native, api, axios

I have an api with jwt authentication enabled. I have the username and password. i want to access, fetch and post data to the api using axios. but using axios.get(url) returns plain html from the url. but if i change the url to any other public unsecured api, then all the data are fetched properly. any help is extremely appreciated

i am using this to fetch from url

```
    axios.get(baseUrl)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.warn(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.warn(error.message);
    });
```

baseUrl is the url of the api

Comment: Which headers do you use?

Comment: i am new to this, i dont know how to use headers. am i supposed to put the username or password inside the headers property of axios? please help

Comment: I would need more information about the api. What is the url ? Do you have an api doc?

Comment: i dont think i can provide you anymore information as it is hosted in a private ip and no documentation was provided to me, as far as i know, the api was developed in grails framework. but i suppose that doesn't matter.

Comment: In case you use jwt usually it's necessary the following header ```Authorization: Bearer <token>```

Comment: i know i am being stupid now, but how do i get the token? i only got the url and username,password

Comment: Can't tell without api information.